# Send Entity Framework form to controller as model using AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am experiencing an issue when trying to send an entity framework form to my controller as a model thru ajax. The problem is that in some cases it doesn't passes an empty model. Here's what I have:

**Manufacturer.cs**

```
public class Manufacturer 
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ManufacturerID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Car.cs**

```
public class Car
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int CarID { get; set; }

    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int ManufacturerID { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public decimal Mpg { get; set; }
}
```

**Manufacturers.cshtml**

```
<div id="manufacturer-list">
    @Html.Partial("ManufacturerList")
</div>
<div id="manufacturer-form">
    @Html.Partial("ManufacturerForm")
</div>
```

**ManufacturerForm.cshtml**

```
@model Manufacturer

<form id="create-manufacturer-form" method="post">
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <a onclick="CreateEntity('@Url.Action("CreateManufacturer", "Home")', 'manufacturer')">Add Manufacturer</a>
</form>
```

**Cars.cshtml**

```
<div id="car-list">
    @Html.Partial("CarList")
</div>
<div id="car-form">
    @Html.Partial("CarForm")
</div>
```

**CarForm.cshtml**

```
@model Car

<form id="create-car-form" method="post">
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <a onclick="CreateEntity('@Url.Action("CreateCar", "Home")', 'car')">Add Car</a>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
function CreateEntity(createAction, modelType) {
    var $form = $('#create-' + modelType + '-form');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: createAction,
        data: $form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            //do stuff
        }
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly CarsDbContext _context;

    public HomeController(CarsDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreateManufacturer(Manufacturer model)
    {
        //do stuff
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreateCar(Car model)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

So in the case of filling out a Manufacturer form and submitting it `$form.serialize()` gives `"ManufacturerID=0&Name=Toyota"`. The Controller action receives a full model with the values given and I can add that model to my database using Entity Framework.

The problem comes when trying to do the same with a Car.  I fill out the form and submit it. `$form.serialize()` gives something like `"CarID=0&Model=Camry&ManufacturerID=1&Year=2010&Mpg=24.4"`.  The Controller action in this case recieves an empty model with `0`s for any value fields and `null` for string fields.

Further inspection into the DOM elements created shows that the form created for Manufacturer has a hidden input field for the ManufacturerID that ends with `value="0">` and the same hidden input for CarID has the attribute `value>`.  Not sure if this is a problem but I figured it was worth noting.

I need to know why I'm receiving a complete model in the case of Manufacturer but not in the case of Car.

Comment: I'm assuming your Controller has a `CreateCar(Car model)`? And Cars.cshtml has `id="car-form"` not `id="manufacturer-form"`? Though the latter wouldn't explain the problem.

Comment: Yes I will fix. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant to post to `CreateCar(Car model)` action method inside your controller,

It seems like a bug inside the default model binder when your posted form data has an item with the name `Model`. If your posted data does not have the `FormData` item with key `Model`, model binding works fine (Hence your manufacturer form worked for you)

It should work if you change the property name from `Model` to `ModelName`

```
public class Car
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int CarID { get; set; }

    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    public int ManufacturerID { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public decimal Mpg { get; set; }
}
```

I will post an update to this answer as i learn more.

Comment: This was it.  Thanks.  @Shyju Do you know if this is because my parameter in the controller action was named 'model' or is it an issue with 'Model' being a sort of reserved word in Entity Framework?

Comment: No.It is because your form data has an item with key `Model`. So if you include an input element like `<input type="text" name="Model" />` inside your manufacturer form, that will also not work (even though you use Car as the parameter of the action method). I filed [an issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7064)  in the asp.net mvc repo  for this and i will update the answer as i hear something from those folks.